# Problem with returning struct from map c++

Tags: c++, struct, mapping

I've been working on my new project in c++ (database of students) made on `std::unordered_map` and I have problem with returning values from map. I have a code:

Preambule.h

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
namespace data
{
    struct student
    {
        std::string name;
        std::string surname;
        uint8_t age;
        uint8_t year;
    };
    student makestudent(std::string m_name, std::string m_surname, uint8_t m_age, uint8_t m_year)
    {
        student s = {m_name, m_surname, m_age, m_year};
        return s;
    };
    void addnew(int ID,std::vector<int8_t> keys,std::unordered_map<int8_t,data::student> students, std::string m_name, std::string m_surname, uint8_t m_age, uint8_t m_year)
    {
        ID += 1;
        keys.push_back(ID);
        students[ID] = makestudent(m_name,m_surname,m_age,m_year);
    }

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "preambule.h"



int main()
{
    int *ID = new int(0);
    std::vector<int8_t>* keys = new std::vector<int8_t>;
    std::unordered_map<int8_t, data::student> *students = new std::unordered_map<int8_t, data::student>;

    data::addnew(*ID,*keys,*students, "name", "surname", /*age*/ 1, /*year*/ 1);
    data::addnew(*ID,*keys,*students, "name", "surname", /*age*/ 1, /*year*/ 1);

    data::student &ben = students[1];
    std::cout << ben.age;

    delete students;
    delete keys;
    delete ID;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After trying to return values from map:

```cpp
data::student &ben = students[1];
```

I keep getting error message:

> non-const lvalue reference to type `data::student` cannot bind to a
> value of unrelated type `std::unordered_map<int8_t, data::student>`
> (aka `unordered_map<signed char, data::student>`)

How can I fix it?

Comment: You probably should not dynamically allocate your vector or map.

Comment: I try to avoid copying data, that is bad idea?

Comment: `void addnew(int ID,std::vector<int8_t> keys,std::unordered_map<int8_t,data::student> students, std::string m_name, std::string m_surname, uint8_t m_age, uint8_t m_year)
    {` should not take the map or vector by value. Instead pass by reference.

Comment: ***I try to avoid copying data, that is bad idea?*** It's usually a bad idea to dynamically allocate a container of the standard library. The container already has the data on the freestore.

Comment: frankly, your attempt to avoid copies is rather misguided. Take for example `int *ID = new int(0);`. You dymically allocate an `int` which is completely unecessary. Then here `data::addnew(*ID,*....` you dereference the pointer to pass *a copy* of that `int` to the function `addnew`. Forget about pointers and pass arguments by reference to avoid copies.

Comment: @AlmostAnEngineer -- *I try to avoid copying data, that is bad idea?* -- Trying to beat the compiler in the optimization game by believing you can write tricky code is a losing battle.  All you will accomplish is to have your code run *slower* than it should, not faster.  Those calls to `new` come with a cost, as the heap manager has to get involved.

Comment: Change `std::unordered_map<...> *students` to `std::unordered_map<...> students` and remove all the unnecessary dynamic allocations (and corresponding deletions). That’s all you need. In C++ you *never* need (and therefore should avoid) raw `new` or `delete` operators (unless you are writing low-level libraries with (e.g.) placement `new` / placement `delete` or some such). If you insist on dynamic allocation, `std::make_unique<std::unordered_map<...>>` is your friend. Anyhow, let `std::unordered_map` and `std::vector` manage heap space for you; don’t introduce a needless extra pointer hop.

Comment: @AlmostAnEngineer *I try to avoid copying data, that is bad idea?* -- You are copying data here: `void addnew(int ID,std::vector<int8_t> keys,std::unordered_map<int8_t,data::student> students,...` -- This is what you should have focused on if you don't want to copy data.  Those vector and map arguments should be passed by reference, not value.  Both the usage of `new` and the passing of parameters by value looks like a Java or C# programmer's attempt at C++ by using Java/C# as a model in writing C++ code.

Comment: Oh, and in `addnew(...)`, do *not* pass the map by value. First it’s completely wrong and, even if it wasn’t wrong, it would be tremendously inefficient. Use a reference there. But ideally don’t use the map itself this way; wrap it into a class called (e.g.) `MyStudentDatabase` as a private member and make `addnew(...)` a method of your class. Then the ownership of the map is abundantly clear and you don’t have to pass it in as a reference. Also, the whole `makestudent(...)` idea is rather inefficient. Use something like `students.try_emplace(key, value constructor arguments);` instead.

Comment: Yet another tip, if you really want to _avoid copying data_: Besides passing the map as a reference (or ideally keeping it as an instance member, which is an equivalent solution), you could also `std::move(...)` the `std::string` arguments into the map’s `try_emplace(...)` or use `std::string_view`s instead of (copied and memory-owning) `std::string`s.

Answer (score 3):

> ```cpp
> data::student &ben = students[1];
> ```

The `students` variable is not of map type here, it's of the pointer type `std::unordered_map<int8_t, data::student> *`, thus the subscript operator actually does a pointer offset operation and dereferences it here (`*(students + 1)`). Instead you probably want to dereference the pointer (to access the underlying map) and take the value by key:

```cpp
data::student &ben = (*students)[1];
```

You will not find the data you expect from the map, however, because the function which is supposed to populate the map with data takes it by value:

```cpp
void addnew(int ID,std::vector<int8_t> keys,std::unordered_map<int8_t,data::student> students, std::string m_name, std::string m_surname, uint8_t m_age, uint8_t m_year)
```

As a result you always instantiate a new copy of the map and all new data comes into this copy, while your original instance never changes. Pass the map by a reference (`std::unordered_map<int8_t,data::student> &students`) or pointer (`std::unordered_map<int8_t,data::student> *students`) if you want to change the original object.

Comment: _"[...] or pointer [...] if you want to change the original object"_ ... can be done via a reference as well. It's not a valid reason to take by address :) Here, there is no need to do all these allocations, and taking by reference (or const-reference if not supposed to be modified) should be the "proper" alternatives.

Comment: @Fareanor i agree, but this is not the question OP is asking about. For this particular snippet there is no reason to allocate the map in dynamic memory, however it's unknown what requirements OP is trying to meet. It might be a simple XY-problem, or it could be some home assignment focused on dynamic memory objects. Either way, despite being unreasonable, a dynamically allocated object is still valid here

Comment: Indeed, but anyway, the note about using the pointer version in case OP wants to modify is still wrong IMHO (since it can be done via a non-const reference as well).

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
data::student &ben = students[1];
```

To:

```
data::student &ben = students->at(1);
```

`students` is a pointer and you need to dereference it before you access member functions like `operator []`